# Trouble thinking of a term or colloquialism for "much much more"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

There is a saying that is on the tip of my tongue that basically means "immeasurably more than".  I think it's related to "factor" but I just cannot place it.  I also feel like it's commonly used in a technically incorrect way but I can't be sure.

Example Sentence:

> The new process is _______________ simpler than the previous one.

I'm almost positive it's math related.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence (and *exact* intended meaning) in which you might use the sought term.

Comment: I added an example sentence. I don't know the *exact* meaning because I think it is typically used in an exaggerative form.

Comment: I've removed my original closevote (based on lack of an example context), so I can't *re-vote* to close (for Primarily Opinion-Based). In your specific example, ***vastly*** (or just plain ***much***) comes to mind, but there are so many alternatives it simply isn't reasonable to suppose there would be a single unambiguously "correct" answer. Perhaps you'd prefer ***infinitely***. (You can't get much more "extreme" than that! :)

Comment: There is a single, unambiguously, correct answer. It's the one I'm thinking of but cannot remember.

Comment: Well like I said, I can't closevote *again*, so I'll play your guessing game a bit longer. If you're looking for a multi-word term, maybe ***far and away*** might work (but I probably wouldn't use it myself in this exact context).

Comment: Added a clue, I'm almost positive it's math related. I had already said I think it's "factor" based but still, hopefully this helps.

Comment: I'd agree with @FumbleFingers, if you really mean "immeasurably more than" in a math related way then *infinitely* seems the word to go with. *Exponentially* might work in some situations but it's not as good a fit.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22factorially+greater%22) are a few instances of ***factorially greater** [than something much smaller].* But I think they're misusing the term anyway.

Comment: I just found it, finally.  Gave you all upvotes for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The "**more**" aspect is already included in the word choice "simpler" of your example sentence. You might consider "**exponentially**", "**immeasurably**", or "**infinitely"** to fill in the blank. Each of these are math related words commonly intended to mean "**vastly**". In fact, you could use that one too.

> The new process is **vastly** simpler than the previous one.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exponentially

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/immeasurably

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vastly

Answer (score 0):

## Order of Magnitude

### References:

https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/orders-of-magnitude/

> Many pretentious writers have begun to use the expression “orders of magnitude” without understanding what it means.

[Usage of "order of magnitude"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437346/usage-of-order-of-magnitude)

["Order of magnitude" for qualitative changes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254631/order-of-magnitude-for-qualitative-changes)

### Usage

incorrectly, but commonly:

> The new process is orders of magnitude simpler than the old one

Or, I believe, correctly:

> The new process is an order of magnitude simpler than the old one

Comment: An ***order of magnitude*** just means ***ten times more***. But in [pretentious, imho] casual parlance it's not normally used very exactly.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying.  And yes, "pretentious", which is why I quoted the WSU article.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a "colloquialism" though. It's a fairly precise mathematical term that's often bandied about in other contexts for its "erudite" associations.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but when I couldn't remember it I was thinking it might be.  Perhaps "idiom" would have been more accurate?